# If $f(x)$ is derivable over $(a,b)$, then there exsits no discontinuity point of the first kind for $f'(x)$ over $(a,b)$.

Tags: proof-verification

## Problem

Assume that $f(x)$ is derivable over $(a,b)$. Prove that there exsits no discontinuity point of the first kind for $f'(x)$ over $(a,b)$.

## Proof

Assume that $f'(x)$ has a discontinuity point of the first kind at $x=x_0$ where $x_0 \in (a,b)$. Then, at least, $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0+}f'(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0-}f'(x)$ both exist. Since $f(x)$ is derivable over $(a,b)$, $f(x)$ is continuous over $[x_0,x_0+h]\subset [x_0,b)$. Thus, by Largrange's Mean Value Theorem, we obtain
$$\lim_{h \to 0+}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0+}\frac{f'(\xi)h}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0+}f'(\xi)=\lim_{\xi \to x_0+}f'(\xi),$$
where $\xi \in (x_0,x_0+h)$. This shows that, at $x=x_0$, the right derivative of $f(x)$ equals the right limit of $f'(x)$. Likewise, we may obatin, at the same point, the left derivative of $f(x)$ equals the left limit of $f'(x)$ too. But, the fact that $f(x)$ is derivable at $x=x_0$ requires that at $x=x_0$ the left and the right derivatives are equal, therefore, the left and the right limits of $f'(x)$ are also equal, whcih shows that $f'(x)$ is contionuous at $x=x_0$. Now, the contradiction comes out.

Comment: Nitpick: One says "differentiable", not "derivable". And the corresponding verb is to "differentiate", not to "derive".

Comment: @MPW But in some documents, the two words are Interchangable. Moreover, in Chinese, the two words, "derivable" and "differentiable" are translated into “可导的” and “可微的”, respectively....

Comment: Even so, that’s from informality or ignorance, not from correctness. It’s a common misuse, a back-formation from the word “derivative”. Of course, you can *define* the word to mean that, and then it’s okay. It’s like saying you can “plus” two numbers to get their sum (instead of saying you can “add” them). I hear that frequently. Everyone can probably guess what you mean, but it isn’t correct usage.